# Segmentation fault while executing with <libssh/sftp.h>

Tags: c, linux, sftp, libssh

I'm trying to execute a program that establishes a SFTP connection, a really simple one, based on the documentation presented in https://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_sftp.html#sftp_subsystem. The .c file is next:

```
#define LIBSSH_STATIC 1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <libssh/sftp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

//int sftp_session(ssh_session session);
//int sftp_directory(ssh_session session, sftp_session sftp_conn);

ssh_session session_1;


int sftp_connection(ssh_session session)
{
    sftp_session sftp_conn;
    int conn_check;

    sftp_conn = sftp_new(session);
    if(sftp_conn == NULL)//If there is not a SFTP connection
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening SFTP session: %s\n", ssh_get_error(session));
        return SSH_ERROR;
    }

    conn_check = sftp_init(sftp_conn);//Initializes a SFTP connection
    if(conn_check != SSH_OK)
    {
        //fprintf(stderr, "Error establishing connection: %s\n", sftp_get_error(sftp_conn));
        sftp_free(sftp_conn);//Frees the connection
        return conn_check;
    }

    sftp_free(sftp_conn);
    return SSH_OK;
}

int main()
{
    sftp_connection(session_1);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, I do the following, in order to statically link the **libssh** library:

`gcc -Wall sftp.c -o sftp -lssh -DLIB_STATIC`

The **sftp** executable is generated, but I get a **Segmentation fault** error. How could I solve it?

Comment: Perchance, where is the [`ssh_new`](https://api.libssh.org/master/group__libssh__session.html#gaadadc0f9601547c30db7c4d62017d32c) call to actually create a session, rather than just pumping a null pointer into `sftp_connection` ?

Comment: compiling with -g -fsanitize=address tells that the sigv is from the call to ssh_get_error :D  so sftp is null and i guess session is null too.

Comment: @WhozCraig now that you mention it, I realize that is a null pointer to a ssh session. I'll try and create a new ssh session.

Comment: The sftp subsystem won't work without a properly prepared session, so .. yeah. You're gonna need one.

Comment: @WhozCraig I've created a SSH session and it's now working fine.

Comment: Documentation : it's what's for dinner.